# clojure.core/map isn't working

Tags: clojure

I am trying to figure out why one of my map calls isn't working. I am building a crawler with the purpose of learning Clojure.

`(use '[clojure.java.io])`

```
(defn md5
  "Generate a md5 checksum for the given string"
  [token]
  (let [hash-bytes
         (doto (java.security.MessageDigest/getInstance "MD5")
               (.reset)
               (.update (.getBytes token)))]
       (.toString
         (new java.math.BigInteger 1 (.digest hash-bytes)) ; Positive and the size of the number
         16)))

(defn full-url [url base]
  (if (re-find #"^http[s]{0,1}://" url)
    url
    (apply str "http://" base (if (= \/ (first url))
                                url
                                (apply str "/" url)))))
(defn get-domain-from-url [url]
  (let [matcher (re-matcher #"http[s]{0,1}://([^/]*)/{0,1}" url)
        domain-match (re-find matcher)]
    (nth domain-match 1)))
(defn crawl [url]
  (do
    (println "-----------------------------------\n")
    (if (.exists (clojure.java.io/as-file (apply str "theinternet/page" (md5 url))))
      (println (apply str url " already crawled ... skiping \n"))
      (let [domain (get-domain-from-url url)
            text (slurp url)
            matcher (re-matcher #"<a[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"\']([^\"\']*)[\"\'][^>]*>(.*)</a\s*>" text)]
        (do
          (spit (apply str "theinternet/page" (md5 url)) text)
          (loop [urls []
               a-tag (re-find matcher)]
            (if a-tag
              (let [u (nth a-tag 1)]
                (recur (conj urls (full-url u domain)) (re-find matcher)))
              (do
                (println (apply str "parsed: " url))
                (println (apply str (map (fn [u]
                                             (apply str "-----> " u "\n")) urls)))
                (map crawl urls)))))))))
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (crawl "http://www.example.com/"))
```

First call to map works:

```
(println (apply str (map (fn [u]
    (apply str "-----> " u "\n")) urls)))
```

But the second call `(map crawl urls)` seems to be ignored.

The `crawl` function is working as intended, slurping the url, parsing with the regex for `a` tags for fetching the href and the accumulation in the `loop` works as intended, but when i call `map` with `crawl` and the `urls` that have been found on the page, the call to `map` is ignored.

Also if I try to call `(map crawl ["http://www.example.com"])` this call is, again, ignored.

I have started my Clojure adventure a couple of weeks ago so any suggestions/criticisms are most welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: There's a tiny mistake in the way you check which pages you've visited: you check if `(str "theinternet/page" (md5 url))` exists, but write the file to `(str "theinternet/" (md5 url))`, so you'll get stuck in a loop because it will look like you didn't crawl the page even when you did.

Comment: Also: useful tip: `let` and `defn` contain an implicit `do`, so can contain multiple expressions - you don't need to explicitly group them together in a `do`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the tip. I have edited the file name in which I write the result of the slurp, I was focused on why `map` wasn't working. I have changed `map` with `doseq` as pointed out and all is working now.

Comment: Great! I hope you enjoy your Clojure adventure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Clojure, `map` is lazy. From the docs, map:

> Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to the
>   set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set
>   of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is
>   exhausted.

Your crawl function is a function with side effects - you're `spit`-ing some results to a file, and `println`-ing to report on progress. But, because `map` returns a lazy sequence, none of these things will happen - the result sequence is never explicitly realized so it can stay lazy.

There are a number of ways of realizing a lazy sequence (that has been created e.g. using `map`), but in this case, as you want to iterate over a sequence using a function that has side-effects, it's probably best to use `doseq`:

> Repeatedly executes body (presumably for side-effects) with
>     bindings and filtering as provided by "for".  Does not retain
>     the head of the sequence. Returns nil.

If you replace the call to `(map crawl urls)` with `(doseq [u urls] (crawl u))`, you should get the desired result.

*Note: your first call to map works as expected because you are realizing the results using `(apply str)`. There is no way to `(apply str)` without evaluating the sequence.*